# VB.NET com base de dados acces

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access, crud

Estou tentando fazer um CRUD aqui utilizando o VB.NET e o Access,
só que quando vou realizar um `INSERT` retorna o erro:

> "Sintax Error in INSERT INTO statement"

Código:

```
con.Open() 

Dim strCmd As String = "INSERT INTO Mapas (DataRegistro,NumReferencia,Local,Responsavel, OBS, Status)" & _ 
                                    "Values (? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? )" 
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCmd, con) 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtDataRegistro.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtMapa.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtLocal.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtResponsavel.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtObs.Text) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", chkStatus.Checked) 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

MsgBox("Mapa cadastrado com sucesso!" & vbCrLf & "Nome.: " & txtMapa.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu particularmente costumo utilizar nomes definidos para cada parâmetro.
Tente dessa maneira:

```
con.Open()
Dim strCmd As String = "INSERT INTO Mapas (DataRegistro,NumReferencia,Local,Responsavel, OBS, Status) values (@DataRegistro,@NumReferencia,@Local,@Responsavel, @OBS, @Status)" 

Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strCmd, con) 

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataRegistro", OleDb.OleDbType.Date)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumReferencia", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Local", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Responsavel", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OBS", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", OleDb.OleDbType.Boolean)

cmd.Parameters("@DataRegistro").value = cdate(txtDataRegistro.Text)
cmd.Parameters("@NumReferencia").value = cint(txtMapa.Text)
cmd.Parameters("@Local").value = txtLocal.Text
cmd.Parameters("@Responsavel").value = txtResponsavel.Text
cmd.Parameters("@OBS").value = txtObs.Text
cmd.Parameters("@Status").value = chkStatus.Checked

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

MsgBox("Mapa cadastrado com sucesso!" & vbCrLf & "Nome.: " & txtMapa.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Observe que eu defini os tipos como imagino que eles estejam em seu banco de dados.
Espero que isso te ajude.

Abraços!